# Are there geometric symmetries in musical harmonics?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, tonnetz

This may be more of an acoustical physics question, but is there something fundamental about wave harmonics that leads to geometric symmetries like a 3:4:5 triangle in a Tonnetz triangle?

The image shows a somewhat modified Tonnetz schema (rotated counter-clockwise to staff orientation) whereby each pitch class & key gets its own domain. Like the more standard Tonnetze, this tone net establishes a matrix of the triads, based on the classical consonances of Maj & minor thirds & the Dominant fifths. However its structure is based on the intersection of pitch classes (here the Y axis) and diatonic keys (the X axis).

[image: Helical tonnetz, pitch/staff orientation]

Is this a known property, that there are right triangles in triadic structures of wave harmonics? Or, in any propagation medium, wouldn't similar relationships between ablative (dissonant) & harmonic (consonant) waveforms arise, perhaps not only in acoustics?

N.b.

1. The 3-4-5 ***ratio*** arises from the ratio of the sides. Putting the harmonic intervals 3 - 4 - 7 on an x-y coordinate graph yields a ratio of 3:4:5. That is, the calculated lengths of the x-y segments on the coordinate graph yield a 3:4:5 triangle, irrespective of the named intervals. The actual spatial offsets of the minor 3rd is larger than 3, the Maj 3rd is > 4, and the 7 semitones of the dominant greater than 7. Please see calculation citations at bottom.
2. The "scale phase" is the regular, descending pattern of scale notes (the grayed tone boxes) that form successive keys (downward, going left-to-right). Note it interlocks periodically with the leading-tone/sub-dominant chain.

**Tonnetz chart features**

1. The Circle of Fifths is a planar projection of a helix;
2. The Circle of Fifths is defined by the hypotenuse of Maj. & minor 3rds;
3. The scale phase, or sweep of scales, is defined by the hypotenuse of a Tritone & Major 3rd;
4. Pitch classes form one axis (here the Y axis),
5. Diatonic Keys the other (here the X axis);
6. Rotated 90 degr. clockwise & the pitches are aligned to the
   standard equilateral triadic matrix, in piano orientation;
7. Rotated 45 degr. clockwise & this schema resembles the Balzano 3rds
   space.
8. Other features arise, including

   - the chain of subdominant and leading tones,
   - the shared pentatonic between adjacent keys (the 2nd, 5th & root of F, C & G, respectively),
   - the ability to visualize non-diatonic & non-triadic chords & cadences

---

### via the [www.triangle-calculator.com](http://www.triangle-calculator.com) OL calculator:##

*** Green Triangle 3:4:5 ***

> Calculating Right Scalene Pythogorean Triangle

[link to calculated Right Pyth. scalene triangle:](https://www.triangle-calculator.com/?what=vc&a=0&a1=0&b=7&b1=1&b2=&c=4&c1=4)

```
note        X,y coord.     actual lengths   factor              base
vectors                                     of 3-4-5 lengths    3:4:5
C → E       0,0 → 4,4       4.243           1.4143333333        3
E → G       4,4 → 7,1       5.657           1.41425             4
C → G       0,0 → 7,1       7.071           1.4142              5
```

*** Red Triangle ***

> Right Scalene Triangle

[link to calculated right scalene triangle:](https://www.triangle-calculator.com/?what=vc&a=0&a1=0&a2=0&b=-4&b1=-4&b2=0&c=-10&c1=2&c2=0)

- C: (0  ,0)
- Eb:(-4,-4)
- A: (-10,2)

Comment: Any additional utility to this tonnetz schema is arguable, although its geo-spatially orthagonal to pitch & key. 

[Equivalence to Cube Dance matrix transforms][1]





  [1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B14eEoqHqa5RMzBYWm9VZGoydHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is "scale phase"?

Comment: Are you mathematically certain that the red triangle is a right triangle?

Comment: I don't understand the geometry in this book, but you might like it: A Geometry of Music: Harmony and Counterpoint in the Extended Common Practice (Oxford Studies in Music Theory) by Dmitri Tymoczko. http://a.co/6DyCpbK

Comment: TY Michael, I've delved into some of Tymoczko's tomes. Amazing stuff, but the 3D tetrahedral reflection of the equilateral triangles are too hard to use visually. But the way he tied it all together is completely amazing, esp. the relationship of the tone-pair helix, to the moebius, torus & 3D tonnetz.

Comment: Yes, @Richard, sorry I should've clarified that right up front. 
I'll edit the question w/ the citation

Comment: And yes, the red triangle is also a right triangle

Comment: I can't say that I'm immediately understanding what you're presenting here but it's reminding me of another thread that took place on this SE.  People were talking about patterns and noting that the intervals of one scale descending are the same as others ascending, such as descending major is the same as ascending phrygian. The person was asking what the significance of this was and the answer was that there really isn't any significance.  It was just the result of the patterns that underlie the diatonic scales/modes.  So, my question here is what sort of value do you hope to gain from this?

Comment: If it doesn't seem fruitful to take the time to explain any of this to me, I certainly won't take offense.  I'm asking more out of curiosity but am somewhat hopeful that I can understand enough to provide some amount of an answer.

Comment: this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-HDDiWWWTU

Comment: This book may interest you  http://dmitri.mycpanel.princeton.edu/geometry-of-music.html

Comment: @Basstickler I think that Chopin tonnetz video answers part of the question. What this particular matrix achieves is to normalize the tonnetz such that group theory can be coupled to a formal spatial analysis.

Comment: @LeebertR.-formerlyBertLee - Thanks for sending that along.  I'll be sure to check that out when I am able.

Comment: An analogy to the 3:4:5 right triangle in mathematics could be the 4:5:6 major chord (justly intonated).

Comment: What does CoF mean? A quick DuckDuckGo search didn't tell me.

Comment: Though so far my thoughts (not confident enough for an answer) is that the axes and angles are arbitrary. It seems that the "highlighted" notes of each scale is not really relevant to the relationship between the notes, so the horizontal axis is the unison interval. I think it would be more explanatory to your "argument" if you demonstrated that more chords beyond major (such as seventh chords) also have this property of forming right angles.

Answer (score 6):

When the *Tonnetz* is laid out like this:

[image]

we see that these triads are not right triangles, but rather equilateral triangles.

So although there are symmetries related to diatonic harmony (and diatonic scales, etc.)---and they are interesting and worth discussing!---the symmetries you are showing and asking about are really just a byproduct of how you've chosen to lay out your *Tonnetz*.

---

With that in mind, note that the consonant triads---major and minor---are both constructed with one minor third and one major third. (The major triad has the major third on bottom with the minor third on top, and the minor triad inverts this.) Furthermore, the remaining interval can be viewed as a perfect fourth.

The minor third is 3 semitones, the major third is 4, and the perfect fourth is 5. So, assuming you lay out your geometrical space correctly, it's quite easy to walk away with a 3:4:5 right triangle.

Comment: I'm left with an open ended conclusion here: Byproduct, or deeper feature? It's a bit like the matter of Amplituhedra or Adinkras in physics. Quantum physicists see them as indicative of the deeper physical properties of the media  (quantum fields), as well as providing  shortcuts to understanding physical phenomena. Their comrades in string theory are heavily into acoustic models, FWIW.

Comment: @BertLee I misunderstood your original question; see edit.

Comment: I should also mention that the shifting scale phase also follows a right triangle, a hypotenuse to Tritones vs. Maj. 3rds. Apophenia or confirmation bias notwithstanding, is something more elegant being overlooked?

Comment: Right but the 3:4:5 is based on the 5ths (7 semitones) arising as the hypotenuse of the Maj & min 3rds. (TY for interjecting there Dave, Richard had me going there for a sec.)

Comment: Yes, but in a mod-12 space 7 semitones can also be mapped as just 5. And the "5" of your 3:4:5 triangle is in fact measuring the perfect fifth (=perfect fourth).

Comment: The dominant 5th you mean? That ratio arises from the ratio of 3 - 4 - 7 on the coordinate plane. That's how that ratio arises, from the calculated lengths of the x-y segments on the coordinate graph. 

That is, after all, how a 3:4:5 triangle is actually formed. After all, the spatial offset of the minor 3rd is larger than 3, the Maj 3rd is > 4, and the 7 semitones > 7. That's the only way the 5 arises, as part of a geometric ratio, and not the named harmonic length, of the hypotenuse.

I'm pressed for time, but I'll try to clarify that in the question.

Comment: Byproduct, not deeper feature.  The overtone series is simple geometry, not ratios of numbers of semitones however tuned.  This _Tonnetz_ may be a convenient way of looking at chords, but it tells you nothing about how sound works.

Comment: Another way of looking at it is that Tonnetze are a visual compression of actual physical states. The actual eurhytmics of harmonics has a physical basis in wave physics. Waveform interference, incl. harmonic partials, is a known property in acoustic science. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonance_and_dissonance

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a known property, that there are right triangles in triadic structures of wave harmonics?

No.  What I'm basing this on is in your use of (right) triangles and the idea of the hypotenuse, which implies quantities that add in *quadrature* ala the Pythagorean theorem.

Our sense of tone is intimately tied to the sounds that are (good approximations of) comprised of a overtone series that are integer multiples of a fundamental, and our sense of harmony only relates to these kinds of sounds.  There is no adding in quadrature here, thus no triangles.

Comment: Perhaps, but I've noted that Elaine Chew has encountered similar relationships in her helical graph. The logarthmic / geometric progression is compressed in any graph we construct in music (assuming 12 TET). But the harmonics are inherent to consonant  & ablative wave interactions. Whether we find one over the other more or less eurythmic seems inherent to acoustical consonances, incl. overtone series...

Point being that a graph is a compression scheme, but it also reveals structure that a linear scale won't show.